# Find a line by searching for a string, then edit a line which is 2 lines below

Tags: vb.net, string, line

My first question here, I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I have a text file that looks like this :

```
[...]
                "tickets"
                {
                    "436"       "320000000400000083421a060100100104"
                    "674"       "320000000400000083421a06010010010a"
                    "292"       "320000000400000083421a0601001001f0"
                    "551"       "320000000400000083421a0601001001da"
                }
                "99550"
                {
                    "informations"      "254"
                    "parameters"        "-banana -lemon"
                }
                "99551"
                {
                    "informations"      "641"
                    "parameters"        "-banana -lemon"
                }
                "550"
                {
                    "informations"      "551"
                    "parameters"        "-banana -lemon"
                }
                "551"
                {
                    "informations"      "123"
                    "parameters"        "-banana -lemon"
                }
                "552"
                {
                    "informations"      "987"
                    "parameters"        "-banana -lemon"
                }
[...]
```

What I want to do is:

- search for this string in the text file :
  `"551"
  {`
- add `-apple` to the parameters line which is 2 lines below, should look like this :
  `"parameters"        "-banana -lemon -apple"`

I think it's the only way to find this line, but I don't get the coding skills to get it done.

Comment: If this is your first time here...welcome! and read up on how to ask a question here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What if there are no values currently in the parameters line?   Will it still have the double quotes with nothing between them?  Will there always be a parameters line if the desired number is present?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Function ReplaceSpecial(ByVal text As String, ByVal find As String, ByVal insert As String) As String
    Dim allLines() As String = Split(text, vbCrLf)
    Dim lineNumber = Array.IndexOf(allLines, find)
    Dim lineToUpdate = Array.FindIndex(Of String)(allLines, lineNumber, Function(f) f.Trim.StartsWith("""parameters"""))
    allLines(lineToUpdate) = allLines(lineToUpdate).Trim.Substring(0, allLines(lineToUpdate).Length - 1) & " " & insert & """"
    Return Join(allLines, vbCrLf)
End Function
```

**Sample Usage:**

Assuming that your input text is in a textbox named `InputTextBox` the following code will show you updated text in `OutputTextBox`.

```
OutputTextBox.Text = ReplaceSpecial(InputTextBox.text, """550""", "-apple")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one, not much different than Pradeep Kumar's submission:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FileName As String = "C:\Users\Mike\Documents\SomeFile.txt"
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(FileName))
    AddParameterToSection(lines, "551", "-apple")
    AddParameterToSection(lines, "552", "-orange")
    File.WriteAllLines(FileName, lines)
End Sub

Private Sub AddParameterToSection(ByVal lines As List(Of String), ByVal sectionID As String, ByVal parameter As String)
    Static DoubleQuote As String = Chr(34)
    Static Parameters As String = DoubleQuote & "parameters" & DoubleQuote
    Static PairOfDoubleQoutes As String = DoubleQuote & DoubleQuote

    Dim header As String = DoubleQuote & sectionID & DoubleQuote
    Dim index As Integer = lines.FindIndex(Function(x) x.Trim() = header)
    If index <> -1 Then
        Dim endBracket As Integer = lines.FindIndex(index, Function(x) x.Trim() = "}")
        Dim paramIndex As Integer = lines.FindIndex(index, Function(x) x.Trim().StartsWith(Parameters))
        If paramIndex <> -1 AndAlso paramIndex < endBracket Then
            If lines(paramIndex).EndsWith(PairOfDoubleQoutes) Then
                lines(paramIndex) = lines(paramIndex).Replace(PairOfDoubleQoutes, DoubleQuote & parameter & DoubleQuote)
            Else
                lines(paramIndex) = lines(paramIndex).TrimEnd(DoubleQuote) & " " & parameter & DoubleQuote
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But if the text contains Tab spaces at start of lines (5 to 6 depending of the line), how to make your code work? http://pastebin.com/CVgsDPC2

Comment: Change `x.StartsWith(..)` to `x.Trim().StartsWith(..)` in **both** places.

Comment: Also need to change the line that sets `endBracket`.  See edited code above.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers! Now your code does nothing. Probably my fault because I neglected spaces between `"parameters"` and `"-banana -lemon"` when I asked my question. Here is how the file exactly looks : http://pastebin.com/k6qHNewD

Comment: I downloaded your file off pastebin and my code worked just fine.  It added  "apple" to the 551 section, and "orange" to the 552 section.  You'll have to do some troubleshooting on your own...

Comment: Probably my fault, forgot to mention that the entire file contains `551` before, I made a better example which contains all cases where you can find `551`. http://pastebin.com/FtTd0xPS

Comment: Try that out...it now matches the entire line for the beginning of the section instead of using StartsWith().

Comment: Last question : Is there a way to check if `-banana` or `-lemon` or wathever on this line exists and delete it?

Comment: It would be pretty much the same code up to the Replace() line with a slight tweak.  I can't post anything now as I've just performed a Clean Install with Win10...and am still rebuilding my system.